# EXCEL - format cells to make negative numbers red and show them with persian numerals

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not familiar with excel formats but I've found these two formats and I need to combine them to have a result of comma separated Persian numbers which negative values are red,

to make negative numbers comma separated and show negative values in red :

```
#,##0_ ;[Red]-#,##0
```

to show numbers with Persian/Arabic numerals:

```
[$-2060000]
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Prepend the 1st format with the 2nd one. Untested but should yield results: `[$-2060000]#,##0_ ;[Red]-#,##0`.

Comment: @JvdV thanks for you comment, it makes the numbers comma separated and Persian, but doesn't make the negative values red

Comment: It does for me when I test this. Not sure what is wrong on your end. `[Red]` needs to be adjusted to your locale maybe. Since my Excel's locale is 'Dutch' I had to write `[Rood]`.

Comment: my locale would be Persian, and the color 'red' would be 'قرمز', but excel won't accept it, and if I set the locale to English the format won't change the color

Comment: Maybe use conditional formatting as a workaround. Red font when <0.

Comment: @bugdrown actually it does work, could you post it so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: @sima ghoreyshi Done, thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your formatting: `[$-2060000]` as a number format shows every negative number as one single minus character.

Comment: @Dominique I know nothing about excel format rules, so I can't explain why, but I've found it in [here](https://superuser.com/a/1153140/1659668)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using conditional formatting as a workaround. Red font when <0.